# PyQt4 GUI Not Showing, calling a converted .ui (xml) file with a separate script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am using pyqt4 for python 3.2 as instructed in B M Harwanis book.
I converted a .ui file (radiobtn.ui) which was created in qt designer to .py format in cmd using 
**pyuic4 radiobtn.ui -o radiobtn.py** and then I created a separate script to call it, but when I run the script in IDLE I get no output.
I stored all the files in **C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4**

Picture of [Designer Widget Layout and Object Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu43w.png)

Code of the seperate script **callradios.py**

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
from radiobtn import *

class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.ComputeButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.calculate)
        self.ui.radioAdd.setChecked(1)

    def calculate(self):
        if len(self.ui.lineFirstNumber.text())!=0:
            a=int(self.ui.lineFirstNumber.text())
        else:
            a = 0
        if len(self.ui.lineSecondNumber.text())!=0:
            b=int(self.ui.lineSecondNumber.text())
        else:
            b = 0
        if self.ui.radioAdd.isChecked()==True:
            result=a+b
        if self.ui.radioSubtract.isChecked()==True:
            result=a-b
        if self.ui.radioMultiply.isChecked()==True:
            result=a*b
        if self.ui.radioDivide.isChecked()==True:
            result=a/b

        self.ui.labelResult.setText("Result: "+str(result))
```

Comment: Where do you create a MyForm object?

Comment: The book never specify the creation of a MyForm object in Qt Designer 
What should I do?